# The CardAction of Hero card in Carousel card not working as actionable button

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I have tried ImBack as a action type in the value field i am getting text. When i click on the Hero card the value which i have written in code is displayed after clicking now the problem is the text should passed as a value in the method so that the method should be called after clicking that. Please provide solution.

```
public static IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments(IDialogContext context)
        {
            return new List<Attachment>()
            {
 GetHeroCard(
                    "NoSQL",
                    "Blazing fast, planet-scale NoSQL",
                    "NoSQL service for highly available, globally distributed apps—take full advantage of SQL and JavaScript over document and key-value data without the hassles of on-premises or virtual machine-based cloud database options.",
                    new CardImage(url: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/media/how-it-works/architecture-resize.png"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Click here", value: "see the below options:")),
};
}
```

Expected Behavior

As from above code, i am getting the card with button name as "Click here" after clicking it my input is given to bot as "see the below options:", After this i want to initiate a function.
I want the value to be passed to the function. So i can handle it further.
Please tell me how i can i use this value of CardAction.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide [mcve] what you have tried.

Comment: public static IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments(IDialogContext context)
{
  return new List<Attachment>()
 {
 GetHeroCard(
    "NoSQL",
   "Blazing fast, planet-scale NoSQL",
  "NoSQL service for highly available, globally distributed apps—take full advantage of SQL based cloud database options.",
                    new CardImage(url: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/media/how-it-works/architecture-resize.png"),
 new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Click here", value: "see the below options:")),
};
}

Comment: Post you code by edit your question instead of putting in comment section. Please read [ask] good question

Comment: After click on that button i want to display a promptDialog

Comment: So when your bot receives _"see the below options:"_ you can initiate your PromptDialog, I don't understand what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the button of a card will just send a new message and it will hit the`MessageReceived` method on your dialog. To perform something different based on the button message, you will have to detect if the upcoming message is the "see the below options:" and if it is, then use a `PromptDialog`.

Something like:

```
var message = await activity;

if (message.Text.ToLower() = ""see the below options:")
{
}
```